# Evaluate pure function through round brackets

Tags: functions, matrix, evaluation, pure-function

In have some matrices of pure functions or numbers which I multiply by other matrices or vectors. I would like the functions to be evaluated in the result, but all that I get is something like this:

```
(I*(D[#1, x] & ))[f[{x, y}]]
```

Instead I would like something like this:

```
I*Derivative[{1, 0}][f][{x, y}]
```

All that I need is that the derivative could pass through the most external round brackets, so that the function could be applied to the argument.

Since I work with a large amount of matrices, I cannot delete manually all the parenthesis after getting the result; is there a way to let the function know it can pass through the brackets?

Thanks.

EDIT:

The solution which best fits my needs is a modified version of @kglr

`f1=#/.head_[a___][d___]:>If[StringMatchQ[ToString[{a}//FullForm],"*Function*"],
head[##&@@({a}/.w_Function:(1*#&):>w[d])],
head[a][d]]&;]`

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! 1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by **answering questions** in your area of expertise. 
2) Take the [tour](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour) and check the [faqs](http://goo.gl/kQNRaS)!   
3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. 
Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t)!

Comment: see [Here](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/87930/5467) for the underlying problem.

Comment: Thank you, now I understand the reason for that behaviour. Nevertheless, the brackets are put automatically by mathematica, even if they are not present when the list which they are part of is defined.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Restructure the `FullForm` using `ReplaceAll`:

```
f1 =  # /. head_[a___][d___] :> head[## & @@ ({a} /. w_Function :> w[d])] &
```

Examples:

```
{#, f1 @ #} &[(((Log@(D[#1, x] &))))[h[{x, y}]] ]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
 {#, f1 @ #} &[(((I (D[#1, x] &) ((D[#1, y] &)))))[h[{x, y}]] ]
```

> [image: Mathematica graphics]

Alternatively, define a function that processes the box forms of the expressions to remove the parentheses:

```
f2 = ToExpression[Replace[ToBoxes[#], {RowBox[{"(", RowBox[{a__}], ")"}] :> 
       RowBox[{a}], RowBox[{RowBox[{a___}], b___, RowBox[{c___}], d___}] :> 
       RowBox[{a, b, c, d}]}, {0, Infinity}]] &;
```

Examples:

```
{I*D[#1, x] &[3 x y z], (I*(D[#1, x] &))[3 x y  z], (I*(D[#1, x] &))[3 x y  z] // f2}
```

> [image: Mathematica graphics]

```
I*D[#1, x] &[h[{x, y}]]
```

> [image: Mathematica graphics]

```
(I*(D[#1, x] &))[h[{x, y}]]
```

> [image: Mathematica graphics]

```
(I*(D[#1, x] &))[h[{x, y}]] // f2
```

> [image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: ... not sure how robust this  is for general expressions.

Comment: Thank you, it seems a good starting point to solve my problem.

Comment: I don't understand very well what the f1 function does, could you explain it to me, please?

Comment: @PPeg, if you look at the `FullForm` of the expression in your post  using `FullForm[(I*(D[#1, x] &))[3 x y z]]` you see that it is seen  by mma as `Times[Complex[0,1], Function[D[Slot[1],x]]][Times[3,x,y,z]]` which has the pattern `head[arg1][arg2]`. The function `f1` transforms such patterns by replacing any `Function` object, i.e., `Function[D[Slot[1], x]]`  within `args1` with `Function[D[Slot[1], x]][args2]`; that is, it pushes `args2` inside the parantheses into the appropriate place. Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you very much. This could be the answer to my question. I will work a bit on it and eventually close the question.

Comment: This function would solve  my problem if it acted only on a `Function`  but, if I apply it on an expression such as `{(f^({0,1}))[{p1,q1}],(-(\!\(
\*SubscriptBox[\(\[PartialD]\), \(q1\)]#1\)&))[g[{p1,q1}]]+(g^({1,0}))[{p1,q1}]}`, which is what I need to do in general, it modifies even the derivatives which are already evaluated. Is it because they don't have a second argument to be pushed inside the first square brackets?