# Problem with Distribute and Composition

Tags: functions, simplifying-expressions, operators

I'm having trouble with the following.
When I try to expand an expression like

```
Through[Distribute[g@*(f@*g + g@*f), Plus]@x]
```

I get what I would expect. That is,

```
g[f[g[x]]] + g[g[f[x]]]
```

However, a minus sign in the parenthesis would yield

```
g[f[g[x]]] + g[(-(g@*f))[x]]
```

instead of the expected

```
g[f[g[x]]] - g[g[f[x]]]
```

What can I do about it?

---

**Edit:**

As suggested by [Carl Woll](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/45431/carl-woll), one can solve this by doing:

```
comp = g @* Inactive[Subtract][f@*g, g@*f];
Activate @* Through @* Distribute[comp, Inactive@Subtract] @ x

(*g[f[g[x]]] - g[g[f[x]]]*)
```

However, I'm still having trouble with the slightly more complicated issue of simplifying the following

```
fcomm[a_, b_] := Inactive[Subtract][a@*b, b@*a];
Nest[fcomm[#, g] &, f, 2]

(*Inactive[Subtract][Inactive[Subtract][f@*g, g@*f]@*g,g@*Inactive[Subtract][f@*g, g@*f]]*)
```

If I now try to do

```
Distribute[Nest[fcomm[#, g] &, f, 2], Inactive[Subtract]]

(* Inactive[Subtract][Inactive[Subtract][Inactive[Subtract][f@*g, g@*f]@*g,g@*Inactive[Subtract][f@*g, g@*f]]] *)
```

The expression does not simplify and picks up an `Inactive[Subtract]` with a single argument. What am I missing here?

Comment: To get one step closer, you could use `Through[Distribute[g@*(f@*g + Minus@*g@*f), Plus][x]]`. Now you still need to specify that the minus sign has to fall through `g`, though. I guess you could do that with a replacement rule.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After reading the answer to [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/87928/multiply-pure-function-with-scalar) other question, I figured out a simple solution by defining a `CompositionSimplify` function as follows:

```
CompositionSimplify[expr_] := (expr //. {
Composition[x_, y_ - z_] :> Composition[x, y] - Composition[x, z],
Composition[y_ - z_, x_] :> Composition[y, x] - Composition[z, x],
Times[x_, Composition[y_, z_]] :> Composition[Times[#, x] &, Composition[y, z]]
})
```

I can then apply this to e.g.:

```
Through@CompositionSimplify[Nest[fcomm[#, g] &, f, 2]]@x
```

and get the right result

```
(* ==> f[g[g[x]]] - 2 g[f[g[x]]] + g[g[f[x]]] *)
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can use [`Inactive`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Inactive.html) and [`Subtract`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Subtract.html)? For example:

```
comp = g @* Inactive[Subtract][f@*g, g@*f];

Activate @* Through @* Distribute[comp, Inactive@Subtract] @ x
```

> g[f[g[x]]] - g[g[f[x]]]

Comment: Thanks a lot. That works nicely in that case. Nonetheless, let `fcomm[a_,b_]:=a@*b-b@*a` and try to apply the same to simplify `Nest[fcomm[#,g]&,f,2]`. This returns the error message >Subtract::argr: Subtract called with 1 argument; 2 arguments are expected. What am I missing here?

Comment: What exactly did you try?

Comment: Let us say that `fcomm[a_,b_]:=Inactive[Subtract][a@*b, b@*a]`. Then, `Nest[fcomm[#, g] &, f, 2]` gives `Inactive[Subtract][Inactive[Subtract][f@*g, g@*f]@*g, g@*Inactive[Subtract][f@*g, g@*f]]`. Now, while e.g. `Distribute[Nest[fcomm[#, g] &, f, 2][[1]], Inactive@Subtract]` works as you show in your example (i.e. yielding `Inactive[Subtract][f@*g@*g, g@*f@*g]`), `Distribute[Nest[fcomm[#, g] &, f, 2], Inactive@Subtract]` does this: `Inactive[Subtract][ Inactive[Subtract][Inactive[Subtract][f@*g, g@*f]@*g, g@*Inactive[Subtract][f@*g, g@*f]]]`. Why could this be?

Comment: Why don't you add this to your question, along with desired outputs when the Composition is applied to a variable?